# Error returning an array of objects from an Angular function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, arrayobject

Good afternoon, I have a problem when I want to return an array of objects from an external function.

I have declared an Object class with 2 properties, its constructor and one that works where I return an array with more than 50 objects for this example I only put 4 objects

```
export class Object {
  formcontrolName: String;
  formcontrolTraducido: String;

  constructor(formcontrolName: String, formcontrolTraducido: String) {
    this.formcontrolName = formcontrolName;
    this.formcontrolTraducido = formcontrolTraducido;
  }

  getData() {
    return [
      { formcontrolName: 'callId', formcontrolTraducido: 'CId' },
      { formcontrolName: 'collegeCareerId', formcontrolTraducido: 'Carrera' },
      {
        formcontrolName: 'collegeDepartmentId',
        formcontrolTraducido: 'Nombre del Departamento/Centro',
      },
      {
        formcontrolName: 'detailedAreaKnowledgeId',
        formcontrolTraducido: 'Campo Detallado',
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want to call from another component the getData function of the Object class, but when returning I get the following error:

**Type '() => { formcontrolName: string; formcontrolTraducido: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Object[]': pop, push, concat, join**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Object } from './object';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 data: Object;
  arrayData: Object[];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrayData = this.data.getData;
    console.log('arrayData: ' + this.arrayData);
  }
```

}

[stackblitz example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drrwul?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I am new to angular and to working with arrays, I would like to know what I can do to solve my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the type for the property `arrayData` is not of type **Object** which is the class that you're using, so a more proper type would be the same as the one that is returned by the method `getData`.

You can get its return type by using the typescript helper type `ReturnType`, so a good way to type this would be like:

```
  arrayData: ReturnType<Object['getData']>;
```

One recommendation that I have is not to use the name `Object` for a class, since it has the same name as `Object` a javascript builtin.

After that the problem that you have here:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrayData = this.data.getData();
    console.log('arrayData: ' + this.arrayData);
  }
```

Is that you are assigning a method to a variable that expects an array of something, that's why you get the error:

```
Type '() => { formcontrolName: string; formcontrolTraducido: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Object[]': pop, push, concat, join
```

You just need to **call** the method like:

```
    this.arrayData = this.data.getData();
```

With that all in mind the final code would look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Object } from './object';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  data: Object;
  arrayData: ReturnType<Object['getData']>;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrayData = this.data.getData();
    console.log('arrayData: ' + this.arrayData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me Daniel, but now another error appears to me, when executing your solution;: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')

Comment: That is probably a runtime error, because you haven't initialized `data` with an instance of `Object`.

You could define data as: `data = new Object('something', 'something')`